# Two LEDs in Series, Measure 24 Volts at Input When Off, 20V When On - Need to Detect State with Microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, adc

I've got a commercial device that has two LEDs on it.  They are wired in series.  Sometimes they are solid "on" and other times they are blinking - I need to detect these two conditions with a microcontroller.

When they are "Off" I measure 24 Volts at their input.  When they are "On" I measure 20V.  So they're clearly switching ground.

So to detect this with a microcontroller my first thought is to put a high resistance voltage divider on the input and then jam that into an ADC pin on the microcontroller.  Does this seem like a reasonable approach or is there something better?

Comment: Can you reverse engineer the circuit of the commercial device to determine if it uses a discrete transistor / FET to switch the LEDs on/off? If so, might be able to connect the logic input to the transistor / FET to your microcontroller. If you don't have a schematic of the device, might be able to look at the traces on PCB to determine how the LEDs are controlled. Posting a picture of the PCB around the LEDs might help to get a better answer.

Comment: You can connect the LED of an opto coupler in series with these LEDs and decode the coupler output. So you don't have to connect the two GND potentials.

Comment: The simplest approach is a resistive divider and an integrated comparator. Lots of micros have one.

Comment: Are you already using a specific micro family?

Comment: Can't reverse engineer - it's all potted.

Yes, an ESP32 and I don't get to vote on that, I'm afraid.

Comment: @MattRedmond Potted doesn't mean you can't reverse engineer it, it just means you need to be *really* dedicated to bother.

Comment: Which ESP32? If it's something like the C3, it does have an ADC but doesn't have an analog comparator. If it's the H2 it does have one.

Comment: I'll have to dig a little more to find out.  For now I'm using a Heltec LoRaWAN development board and their data sheet and schematics don't indicate which chip is on there.  There is a later version of the same board and they switched chips.  Maybe between the two one will have a comparator.

Comment: @Jens Your proposal actually was most productive in the end.   They are PWMing the LEDs with voltage between 24 and 20.  Current limited by something I don't quite understand.  

Stuck an optocoupler in series with a cap on the output to smooth out the PWM noise.  Works like a charm.

Thanks EVERYONE for the input and help.  This was tough for me.  I'm not a EE.  I studied biology :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now assume that you're using the [analog comparator](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32h2/api-reference/peripherals/ana_cmpr.html) on an ESP32-H2. The source is on GPIO11, and the reference is on GPIO10.

Assume Vdd = 3.3V. Maximum comparator reference is 0.7 * 3.3V = 2.31 V, but you can use the internal reference instead of an external reference. `ref_volt` can take [0% to 70%](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32h2/api-reference/peripherals/ana_cmpr.html?highlight=vdd#_CPPv422ana_cmpr_ref_voltage_t) in 10% steps. For simplicity configure for 50% (i.e. 1.65 V).

The division ratio will then be based on the halfway point between the low and high levels:

$$\frac {0.5 \cdot 3.3} {22} = 0.075 $$
$$ 0.075 = \frac {R_2} {R_1 + R_2} $$
$$ \frac {R_1} {R_2} \approx 12.33 $$

Check that at 24 V, the input level is safe:

$$ \frac {24} {1 + 12.33} = 1.8 < 3.3 $$

Nominal [pin capacitance](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-h2_datasheet_en.pdf) is 2 pF and input current at most 50 nA. Assuming this parasitic DC model:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbb4Jc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You'll want a protection Schottky (D1), something common like the 1N5817. It will probably have a reverse leakage current larger than 50 nA. Assuming 1 uA,

$$V_o = R_2 (Il + (22 - V_o)/R_1)$$
$$V_o = R_2 Il + R_2/R_1 (22 - V_o)$$
$$V_o(1 + R_2/R_1) = R_2 Il + 22 R_2/R_1$$
$$V_o(1 + 1/12.33) = R_2 Il + 22/12.33$$
$$V_o = \frac {R_2 Il + 22/12.33} {1 + 1/12.33} $$

If R2 is 0, the output of the divider is perfectly accurate at 1.65 V. If we only tolerate 5% error, then R2 can be at most ~89k. Something like 22k will be safe and will produce ~1.67 V (before taking into account resistor variation, diode leakage variation, divider error etc.). This would produce an R1 of 270k.

You haven't described the switching rate. You'll want to add a filter cap based on the above and the pin capacitance to filter out noise at a frequency higher than this rate.

Comment: I'm going to call this the answer because even if my ESP32 turns out not to have the comparator, you've gotten me in the right direction and I think I can get this done either way.  Thanks!!